# Offsetof alternative for modern C++

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to add a map to my datatype that maps member name strings to the local offset of the member variable like this:

```
struct E
{
   B memberX;
   B memberY;

   constexpr static entry map[] = {
      { "memberX", offsetof( E, memberX ) },
      { "memberY", offsetof( E, memberY) }
   };
};
```

This doesn't compile with VS2015. If fails at { "memberX", offsetof( E, memberX ) }, with error C2227.

Besides, I know that offsetof doesn't work reliably for non pod types.

Do you have a suggestion how to do what I want in a compatible, modern way?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need to do this? What could you possibly do with information that has no semantics?

Comment: *"with error C2227"* And what is that ominous error C2227?

Comment: I want to generate a map statically at compiletime that maps member names as strings to the actual address of the variable.

Comment: Why not put &memberX ?

Comment: Error C2027 is the important one, always start from the top of the error list.  Move *map* outside of the struct definition.

Comment: You cannot use `offsetof(E, ...)` on an incomplete type `E`, so you need to move `map` definition outside (after `E` is completely defined).

Comment: I cannot build the map outside of the class because In the future I want to combine the definition of the variables and the generation of the mapping into one macro call.

Comment: Besides, E may get a constructor in the future which means it isn't pod anymore (regarding offsetof).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to use the offsets only to access the members later. In that case and given that all members have the same type, a pointer-to-data-member is probably safer and more general:

```
struct E
{
    B memberX;
    B memberY;

    static const auto& getMemberMap {
        static const std::map<std::string, B E::*> memberMap {
            { "memberX", &E::memberX },
            { "memberY", &E::memberY }
        };
        return memberMap;
    };

    B& getMember(const std::string& str) {
        auto it = getMemberMap().find(str);
        if(it == getMemberMap().end()) {
            // throw some exception
        }
        return this->*(it->second);
    };
};
```

`std::map` does not have a `constexpr` constructor, so the map will be built runtime rather than compile-time, but you can replace it with your own implementation.

I used a local static variable instead of a static member because you required the initializiation to be contained in the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

Not that this way is modern, but offsetof is often defined as following:
`#define offsetof(type, memb) (intptr_t)&(((type)NULL)->memb)`
so you can try using that as alternative.